# Html form and Rest Api Django

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework

I am sending a Username and password from my HTML form to django backend .

```
<html> 

<style type="text/css">

    #center_align{
     width: 200px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

</style>        

<head>
  <title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div id = "center_align">
      <h1>Login</h1>
                <form method = "GET" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/" >
                  Username :<input type ="text" name = "username"><br>
                      Password :<input type ="password" name = "password"><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
          </form>
                 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my django , i have wrote a class in my Views

```
class Login(APIView):

    global User_Grps

    def get(request,self):

        state = ""
        username = "Gauss"
        password = settings.AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD

        oLdap = LDAPBackend()

        try:
            User = oLdap.authenticate(username=username,password=password) 
            print User.ldap_user.group_dns

            if User is not None:
                User_Grps = User.ldap_user.group_dns

            else:
                User_Grps = "Invalid Group"

        except Exception as e:
                User_Grps = "Error"

        return HttpResponse(User_Grps)
```

How would i retrieve my username and password from the request object ? Like i need to get the data from the request parameter of the method .

Comment: I don't understand why you are using an APIView here, or even django-rest-framework at all. It looks like you are doing a standard form submit, so you should use a standard Django view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that, you should write a [custom Django authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) which would let you use the default login views from DRF and/or other Django 3rd parties.